# Android: How to pick different different res folder based on package name in gradle

Tags: android, gradle, android-resources

I am developing android application which is similar to another application on the basis of UI and some code functionality to have the code reuse i have created a Appcommon which will be having the common code ( java and res ) of both the application and i have added this appcommon as include in both app gradle. ( Motivation: by making the code common it will be easy to make the bug fix in both app by single effort)

Now i have partitioned the res folder as below in appcommon and both the app also have their res folder too.

```
res
|
 --res_common
 --res_app1
 --res_app2
```

now when i am making the gradle for the appcommon i want to add a check for picking the respective res folder based on the app which user is building. can someone please tell how to achieve this?

**More Details:**
i have two app -> 
1. app1 
2. app2

and i have another app which is appcommon this is not a independent app but it contains the common files among both the app and it also has its gradle file.
so the seeting.gradle file of app1 is like this:

```
include ':app1', ':GatherLibBrowser'

include ':appcommon'
project(':appcommon').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../libs/appcommon')
```

And now app common has the res of two apps (app1 and app2) so in its gradle it needs to detect which app is going to build so that it can pick that respective res folder for that app( it can be either app1 or app2). 
Let me know in case of any confusion.

Comment: [Check this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Gradle_Build_Variants_Example)

Comment: @MD this link how to create separate variant of same app but my problem is that i need to decide which folder to pick in the appcommon gradle based on the app user is trying to build. both the app are different but both have included the app_common in their gradle and now appcommon gradle need to understand for which app it is building so that it can pick the respective app folder.

Comment: Well, that sounds exactly what app flavors are for.

Comment: I think it is different.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the path on `Build.gradle`:

```
android 
{

//...............
 sourceSets
 {
       main
       {
           //here choose your paths
           res.srcDirs =
            [
                   'src/main/res/layout',
                   'src/main/res/layout/splash',
                   'src/main/res/layout-xlarge-land',
                   'src/main/res/layout-xlarge-land/splash',
                    'src/main/res'
            ]

                 //...............
       }//end main

  }//end sourceSets

}//end Android
```

Comment: Thanks for answer But how to decide which folder to pick as that depend on which app is going to build. so i need to add some kind of if condition in res.srcDirs based on the package which i going to be build. That's the question.

Comment: As far as I know when you compile a project you load automatically all `resources` you choosen on paths because in my opinion, a project have only a package... then... why it would change the application package? that is, if you change the package, you change your application and therefore `build.gradle` file... Sorry but I'm so confused right now, I don't understood what do you needed.

Comment: i have elaborated the things more in the main question. let me know if still i am not clear.

Comment: ahhh okok, now I'ts clearly. I don't know but if I had to do something similar, I would create two different `build.gradles` one for each installation....maybe it's not the best solution but... I don't know another one, sorry.